# I am trying make Docusign API call

Tags: docusignapi

I am trying call the API https://realestate.docusign.com/restapi/v1/rooms?dateRangeType=LastUpdated&roomStatus=Open&startDate=2018-12-06
But I get error response as below:
{
    "message": "Unauthorized authentication in production",
    "errorCode": null
}

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using `realestate.docusign.com`, so you are hitting PROD rooms API url, please verify if the user whose credentials you are using is active in PROD Rooms and is correctly linked with PROD Account Server and also verify if the Integrator Key is Live in PROD Account.